# When and how do I specify my AdMob App ID in my app when my entire project is on GitHub?

Tags: android, git, admob, ads, production

According to this, https://developers.google.com/admob/android/banner

I'm told not to use my actual ID while testing my app, until I put the app into production. But, my project is on GitHub, so all code that I write will be open for anyone to see.

So, what am I supposed to do with my AdMob ID?

Checkout a commit, replace the ID with my own, build an apk, upload to playstore, then revert to my commit?

I feel this is too complex, and actual developers don't do this. FYI, I'm entirely new to Android Development, and I have just seen how to put ads.

Comment: API keys shouldn't be committed to source control. You are able to define these in environment or property files that you do not commit. Here's an example of how to do this for Android https://medium.com/code-better/hiding-api-keys-from-your-android-repository-b23f5598b906

Comment: The article mentions two types of _buildTypes_ : (1) Debug (2) Release. I assume when I'm exporting the final apk, Android Studio will automatically use the _Release_ version of the variable, without me having to re verify the code/value of the keys.